# Why do I get string of seemingly random number from this code?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 1

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int i;
  int c;
  char s[LIM];

  for (i=0; i < LIM-1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
  {
    s[i] = c;
  }
  printf("%d\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is for instance: 1541348039 
I am expecting it to be 1.

Comment: `%d` takes an `int`, not a `char *`.

Comment: You loop never executes.  So you see whatever is stored in the allocated memory.

Comment: `#define LIM 1` too small --> `#define LIM 100` , `char s[LIM] = {0};` or add `s[i] = 0;` after for-loop ,  `printf("%d\n", s);` --> `printf("%s\n", s);`

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d\n",*s)`
or
`printf("%d\n",s[0])`

Right now you are trying to print the address of s. s is an array of one character so you need to point to the element you want to print.

Edit:
Also, you need to increment the value of LIM because the condition inside the for is always false.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code. The first one is that you have to change the condition `i < LIM-1` in your code to `i < LIM`, otherwise the loop will never run, because `LIM-1` is equal to 0 and `i` is never less than 0.

The second issue is with the `printf`. If you do `printf("%d\n", s);` then you are asking C to print `s` as an integer. In this case, this will print the memory address of `s`. What you want is

```
printf("%c\n", s[0]);
```

which will print the only character of `s`. Note that you might want to make `s` a null terminated string, in which case you could print all of it (not just the first character) with:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Of course making `s` a null terminated string would require to increase its size, since you would need an extra character for the null. Also, in that case, you have to use the `i < LIM-1` condition in the loop to leave room for the null byte.